# how to fetch values from a table into a table of records

Tags: plsql

I need to create a function which would return a table of records. The filtering will be performed based on a IN parameter of the function.

Generally, it would be very easily performed with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A 
(
  TEST_1 NUMBER 
, TEST_A VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) 
, TEST_B VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) 
) ;



Insert into TABLE_A (TEST_1,TEST_A,TEST_B) values (1,'a','b');
Insert into TABLE_A (TEST_1,TEST_A,TEST_B) values (2,'a','b');


create or replace package test_package as
   type rec is record 
      ( t1 table_a.test_1%type
      , t2 table_a.test_a%type
      , t3 table_a.test_b%type
      );


    TYPE col_table_1 is table of rec;

    function test_plsql_table(par1 varchar2) return col_table_1 pipelined;

end;


create or replace package body test_package as

  function test_plsql_table(par1 varchar2) return col_table_1 PIPELINED as

    cursor temp_cur is
      SELECT * FROM table_a where test_a = par1;
  begin
    for cur_rec in temp_cur loop
      pipe row(cur_rec);
    end loop;
  end;
end;

SELECT * from TABLE( test_package.test_plsql_table('a'));
```

but the problem raises when I want to change the structure of rec record into

```
...
   type rec is record 
      ( t0 UROWID
      , t1 table_a.test_1%type
      , t2 table_a.test_a%type
      , t3 table_a.test_b%type
      );
...
```

adding the new t0 column if type UROWID generates me the error:

> PLS-00630: pipelined functions must have a supported collection return
>   type

but how can I solve it?

thanks a lot.

Comment: `table A` needs to altered, and new `t0` has to be added

Answer (score 0):

```
PLS-00630:     pipelined functions must have a supported collection return type.
```

Cause:      A pipelined function was specified with an unsupported return type.    The following are `not` supported as return types of pipelined functions:

```
- non-collections,

- PL/SQL tables,

- associative arrays,

- collections of PL/SQL types: rowid, mlslabel, long, long raw, boolean, binary_integer, pls_integer, string and urowid
```

The following restrictions apply:

```
   - If the return type is a collection of records, then each of the attributes of the record must be a supported type.

    - A collection of records must not contain a record type as one of its attributes.
```

Action: Specify a supported collection type as the pipelined function return type.

Documentation:-
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2375082?tstart=0

Comment: Yes, indeed, the PIPELINED option doesn't allow returning UROWID dataype. Is there any way to accomplish my task even without using this option? Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below illustration helps you to overcome the issues.

```
    --Table Creation
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A
  (
    TEST_1 NUMBER ,
    TEST_A VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) ,
    TEST_B VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
  ) ;

--Data Insertion
INSERT INTO TABLE_A
  (TEST_1,TEST_A,TEST_B
  ) VALUES
  (1,'a','b'
  );
INSERT INTO TABLE_A
  (TEST_1,TEST_A,TEST_B
  ) VALUES
  (2,'a','b'
  );

    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE REC IS OBJECT
  (
    t1 NUMBER,
    t2 VARCHAR2(1) ,
    t3 VARCHAR2(1) ,
    t0 VARCHAR2(100)); --This can handle the ROWID part too 


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE REC_TAB IS TABLE OF REC;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_package
AS
  FUNCTION test_plsql_table
    (
      par1 VARCHAR2
    )
    RETURN REC_TAB;
END;

SHOW ERROR;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE body test_package
AS
FUNCTION test_plsql_table
  (
    par1 VARCHAR2
  )
  RETURN REC_TAB
AS
lv_tab REC_TAB;
BEGIN
  SELECT rec(test_1,test_a,test_b,ROWID) BULK COLLECT INTO lv_tab FROM TABLE_A
  WHERE test_a = par1;
  RETURN lv_tab;
END;
END;

--Function execution
SELECT * FROM TABLE(test_package.test_plsql_table('a'));
```

Comment: well, the requirements are: one column should be UROWID and there should be used TABLE of RECORDs

Comment: So u want to put ROWID in UROWID Datatype? Is it so?

Comment: yes, that's right and also need to use TABLE of RECORDs

Comment: With Record type its not possible. Although it is possible with SQL object type. And also you can put the ROWID filed in VARCHAR field also.